# Find range of strings

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have some strings in the following format:

There is ______ appels

There is ______ cows and ______ sheep

There is ______ red flowers, ______ green flowers and ______ yellow flowers

Where the ______ represents the editable part of the string.

These strings is contained in a UITextView, but I only want the ______ fields to be editable and the rest of the strings readonly.

I have tried to implement the `"textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String)"` method in order to restrict the edit in the range where the ______ is present. But I am having some trouble calculating the range of the ______ strings.

I have subclassed UITextView, added a  variable:

```
var characterWhereEditIsAllowed: Character = "_"
```

and tried to calculate the range from the first occurence of the "characterWhereEditIsAllowed" to the last like so:

```
guard let editableChracter = editableCharacter else {
   return
}

guard let idx = text.characters.indexOf(editableChracter) else {
   return
}

editableCharacterStartIndex = text.startIndex.distanceTo(idx)
```

I am stuck finding the index of the last occurrence of "_" in the textview text. The help is appreciated.

P.S: I have tried using the "rangeOfString" method, but since the "______" fields are various sized, I can't check on that specific length "string".

Comment: How about using a regular expression to find all instances of "_" with various lengths? `NSRegularExpression` will return an array of ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regex:

```
let text = "There is ______ red flowers, ______ green flowers and ______ yellow flowers"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_+", options: [])
let matchRanges = regex.matchesInString(text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)).map { $0.range }

print(matchRanges) // matchRanges is an Array<NSRange>
```